# rspec no route error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, match, routes

I have set up the path in route.rb as the following:
post "/orders/:id/capture/.:format"

but when I write the controller's rspec 
post "capture"

I got error: "can't find route {:controller => :orders, :action => :capture}

why is that?

Comment: here is my code in controller
`class OrdersController < ApplicationController
def capture
    params.delete('limit')
    failed = nil

    @order = Order.find(:first, :conditions => {
      external_transaction_id: params['external_transaction_id'],
      external_vendor: params['external_vendor']
    }) 
    if PaymentProcessor.capture @order
      Message.delay.user_order_notification(order_id: @order.id)

      raise "There was an error with your order." if failed
    else
      raise "Could not capture order"
    end `

Comment: here is what is in my routes.rb
`post      "orders/:id/capture(.:format)", :controller => :orders, :action => :capture`

Comment: here is my setup in order controller spec
 `context "capture orders" do
  before {@message = mock('Message', deliver: true)
           PaymentProcessor.stub(:capture).and_return{true}
  #     }
  #   it "should send out order receipt after order is captured" do
  #     Message.stub_chain(:delay, :user_order_notification).and_return(@message)
   Message.should_receive(:delay)
     post "capture", :order => @order, :format => :json
   end`

Comment: can you post the code in the question? pretty hard to read it in the comments

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely because you are not passing in the order's id.

The route will not match unless all criteria are met.

In your code you have

```
 post "capture", :order => @order, :format => :json
```

Is @order set?